# Multiple flash instances or a single one?

Tags: flash

I have a doubt: When you open various flash pages in tabs, for example in Firefox, all those pages share the same Flash instance or each one use an instance of flash??

Bye!

Answer (score 1):

> The LocalConnection class lets you communicate between different Flash Player and AIR instances, such as a SWF in an HTML container or in an embedded or stand-alone player. This allows you to build very versatile applications that can share data between Flash Player and AIR instances, such as SWF files running in a web browser or embedded in desktop applications.

(Source: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_4.html)

My interpretation of that piece of text is: `[...] Flash Player [...] instances`, `such as SWF files running in a web browser`:

Every object-tag in HTML is essentially a different application. Though, the applications may share resources, they are definitely not a shared "instance".